# ng-options dynamically as per total count

Tags: angularjs

I have totalcount as 585. Need options values (totalcount/10) based on totalcount dynamically. Like 1,2,3,4,5,6. Previously:

```
<div class="form-inline pull-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Entries</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <select ng-model="$ctrl.entries" class="input-sm border-radius-none form-control">
                        <option ng-value="10">10</option>
                        <option ng-value="20">20</option>
                        <option ng-value="30">30</option>
                        <option ng-value="40">40</option>
                        <option ng-value="50">50</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            <span>

            </span>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ngOptions` directive to populate the options

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      this.entries = 1;
      this.totalcount = 58;
      this.populate = function() {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.totalcount / 10; i++)
          arr.push(i + 1);
        return arr;
      }
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller as $ctrl">
    <label>Total Count</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.totalcount">
    <br>
    <label>Entries</label>
    <select ng-model="$ctrl.entries" ng-options="o as o for o in $ctrl.populate()">
    </select>
    
    <br>
    {{$ctrl.populate()}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to created a array of numbers. Use following code :

```
arrOfNums = [];
let arrLength = $scope.totalCount%10 + 1;
for(let i = 1; i < arrLength; i++) {
 arrOfNums.push(i*10);
}
```

Now you have array. Use this array in your template.
Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this, if you don't feel like creating an extra function in your controller

```
ng-options=" n as n for n in [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]"
```